# I can't solve this error " Column 'Nume_elev' cannot be null "

Tags: php, mysql

[Table here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIkaF.png)
I can't find the problem ,after starring at it for about 2 hours. This is the output:...... oh so in need to post even more details ignore this thing exactly what i wanted ....

[image: This is the output]

```
if(empty($data_missing)){
    require_once('./mysqli_connect.php');

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc,"INSERT INTO elev( Nume_elev, Nume_Parinte, Numar_tel, Numar_Tel_P, ADRESA, elev_id) VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NULL)");
    if($stmt === FALSE){ die(mysqli_error($dbc)); }
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sssss", $Nume_elev, $Nume_Parinte, $Numar_tel, $Numar_Tel_P, $ADRESA);

  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $affected_rows = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);

    if($affected_rows == 1){

        echo 'Student Entered';

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

        mysqli_close($dbc);

    } else {

        echo 'Error Occurred<br />';
        echo mysqli_error($dbc);
       mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

        mysqli_close($dbc);

    }

} else {

    echo 'You need to enter the following data<br />';

    foreach($data_missing as $missing){

        echo "$missing<br />";

    }

}

}

?>
```

Comment: What is `$Nume_elev`?

Comment: can you please show the elev table (database) structure ?

Comment: You shouldn't insert NULL into `elev_id` as it's an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, just leave it out of the INSERT completely. That's not your error though.

Comment: @chris85 it's Romanian for $student_name

Comment: @GeorgeNetu it is a variable, talking about the contents, not the actual variable names meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use the NULL value for the auto increment column

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc,"INSERT INTO elev( Nume_elev, Nume_Parinte, Numar_tel, Numar_Tel_P, ADRESA) 
VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sssss", $Nume_elev, $Nume_Parinte, $Numar_tel, $Numar_Tel_P, $ADRESA);
```

Also check the value of $Nume_elev. since you declared the column Nume_elev not to be null in database, it wont accept NULL or '' value while inserting data in to database.

Please decide what column values to be NULL and make the changes in the database table accordingly.

Comment: it helped me , thanks .Now i got another error :D *i want to cry*
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') VALUES( s, s, s, s, s)' at line 1